# Cakephp special field merge with current field list

Tags: php, cakephp

I have below query in model:

```
$params = array(
                    'fields' => array('User.id','User.username', 'User.lat', 'User.lng', 'User.thumbnail_image', 'User.status', 
                    "6371 * ACos( Cos( RADIANS( User.lat ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( $lat ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( $lng ) - RADIANS( User.lng ) ) + Sin( RADIANS( User.lat ) ) * Sin( RADIANS( $lat ) ) ) AS distance"),

                    'recursive' => 1,
                    'limit' => 15,
                    'offset' => $offset,
                    //'conditions' => array('Friend.user_id' => $user_id, 'Interest.interest' => $interest, 'Favourite.favourite' => $favourite),
                    //'order' => array($order)
                    );

        $find = $this->find('all',$params);

        return $find;
```

Above generates something like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [username] => hybmg571
                    [lat] => 12
                    [lng] => 22
                    [thumbnail_image] => 
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [distance] => 1083.10516386871
                )
```

What I want is to incorporate this distance with User array.
Is there a way we can incorporate distance into User key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields).

```
$this->virtualFields = array(    
    'distance' => "6371 * ACos( Cos( RADIANS( User.lat ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( $lat ) ) * Cos( RADIANS( $lng ) - RADIANS( User.lng ) ) + Sin( RADIANS( User.lat ) ) * Sin( RADIANS( $lat ) ) )"
);
```

(or if the model already has virtual fields, `$this->virtualFields[ 'distance' ] = "..."`)